# Сбрасывается тема до дефолта Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Кастомизировл тему на WP. С ним обычно не сталкивался, так как пишу на другом языке. Проблема в том, что тема сбрасывается до дефолтной. Причину найти не могу. Может где-то косяк в коде, а я его пропускаю? Прикрепляю файлы, которые менял.

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package business-lander
 */

?>
</div>
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
 <div class="footer-widgets">
  <div class="container">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="bottombar">
  <div class="container">
      <?php
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='ru'){
    ?>
  Some text

    <?php }elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){
    ?>
 Some text

    <?php }elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='lv'){
    ?>
 Some text

    
    <?php
    }
  ?> 
  
  <?php
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='lv'){
    ?>
    <p><a href="#">
    Sazinies ar mums   </a></p>
    <?php }elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){
    ?>
    <p><a href="#">
    Contact Us   </a></p>
    <?php }elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='ru'){
    ?>
    <p><a href="#">
    Связаться с нами   </a></p>
    <?php
    }
  ?> 
   <span>
    <?php
     $copyright_default = __( '<a href="https://wordpress.org/">Proudly powered by WordPress.</a> Theme: Business Lander by <a href="https://gretathemes.com/" rel="designer">GretaThemes</a>.', 'business-lander' );
     $copyright = get_theme_mod( 'footer_copyright', $copyright_default );
     echo wp_kses_post( $copyright );
    ?>
   </span>

    <?php
    if ( function_exists( 'jetpack_social_menu' ) ) {
     jetpack_social_menu();
    }
    ?>

  </div>
 </div>

</footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->
<a href="" class="scroll-to-top hidden"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что значит - сбрасывается тема? До какой - дефолтной? Какие действия к этому приводят? Как это сказывается на том файле, что вы приложили?

Comment: как только применяется тема для вордпрес, она является дефолтной без кастомного кода. Я изменяю три файла и вписываю туда свой код. На следующий день сайт выглядит так, как будто В нем ничего не менялось. Даже css первоначального вида, который дает тема. В чем проблема - я понять не могу. Мне сказали что wp так реагирует когда ошибка где-то в коде. Но я не могу ее найти. Я изменял три файла. Тот, что здесь - футер. Могу прикрепить остальные

Comment: Не надо править темы или плагины, а тем более ядро WordPress. Создайте дочернюю тему https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html и вносите все правки там.

Comment: Но то, что вы рассказываете, всё равно какая-то мистика. И ошибки тут ни при чём.

Comment: Короче вы скорее всего правите стандартную тему ВП и она обновляется автоматически при обновлении ядра)

Comment: суть было в том, что хостер имел возможность обновлять тему и это сбрасывало ее до такого состояния